# Hive Query fails for HDFS user

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-yarn

If I run the hive shell as myself I can query tables.

but if I run hive shell using `sudo -u hdfs hive`

then all my queries fail with the error message

```
Application application_1447966350718_10654 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1447966350718_10654_000002 exited with exitCode: -1000
For more detailed output, check application tracking page:http://vtdevana-cloudera11.dealer.ddc:8088/proxy/application_1447966350718_10654/Then, click on links to logs of each attempt.
Diagnostics: Application application_1447966350718_10654 initialization failed (exitCode=255) with output: main : command provided 0
main : user is nobody
main : requested yarn user is hdfs
Can't create directory /yarn/nm/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1447966350718_10654 - Permission denied
Did not create any app directories
Failing this attempt. Failing the application.
```

what should I do so that I can query hive using the hdfs user?

Answer (score 2):

"`/yarn/nm/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1447966350718_10654`" is a path on local file system.

In your `yarn-site.xml`, there is configuration parameter: `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs`.

The description of this parameter is:

> List of directories to store
>   localized files in. An application's localized file directory will be
>   found in:
>   `${yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs}/usercache/${user}/appcache/application_${appid}`.
>   Individual containers' work directories, called container_${contid},
>   will be subdirectories of this.

So, in your case, this parameter has been set to:

```
yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs=/yarn/nm/
```

So, when you try to execute the Hive query as user `hdfs` it tries to create following folder in your local file system and due to lack of permissions, the operation fails:

```
${yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs}/usercache/${user}/appcache/application_${appid}
```

gets translated into

```
/yarn/nm/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1447966350718_10654
```

> "`${yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs}`" is replaced by "`/yarn/nm`"
>   "`${user}"` is replaced by "`hdfs`"
>   "`${appid}`" is replaced by "`1447966350718_10654`"

To solve this problem, you need to give write permissions to all the users to the top level folder: `/yarn/nm/`